# Realized accidental downvote way too late

Tags: support, down-votes, undo

I don't care about the point I lost, I just want to give [the chap who answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4000741/1708136) back his twenty points. His bash for loop template helped me out a lot.

Comment: This is very noble of you. Just so you know though, downvotes are -2 rep, not -20.

Comment: One dirty way to enable voting again is to *trivial-edit* his question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I tried to make a trivial edit to the question, but I think my edit was rejected because it was... well... *too trivial*. I guess I'll try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change your vote at this point if the post is edited.

There really wasn't anything truly worth editing, but I did it anyways. Bleh.

You can change your vote now.