# Can you check how much reputation you have from suggested edits?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

When I first started on SE, I thought that making edits was a cheap way to earn reputation, I'd notice the same people making tiny edits to what seemed like almost every answer and question, what I perceived as an apparent attempt to hoard easy reputation. Just recently I noticed something that made me kind of happy:

> ### [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)
>
> [...]
>  
>   **You gain reputation when:** 
>   
> [...]
>  
>    - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to ***+1000 total*** per user)

Fortunately, there's a cap on how much easy rep you can accumulate.

So now I'm curious, is there somewhere you can check to see how much of your total, allowed, edit rep you've earned is? When you reach the maximum, are you notified that you're at your max and don't get anymore rep? What happens when you have enough reputation for edits to be applied automatically? Do you still collect reputation for edits after that or do you simply lose the perk at that point?

Comment: See also: [How Many Users Have Received 1000 Rep from Edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221714/262755)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to the hidden (and mostly deprecated) `http://{stackexchangesite}/reputation`<sup>1</sup> URL, you'll see at the *very* bottom of the page something like:

```
earned 328 reputation from suggested edits
```

As far as I know that's the only place where that is displayed. (And, of course, you can only see your own.)

Unless you've attracted a fair amount of downvotes on your other content, you should reach the 2000 reputation "edit everywhere" privilege *before* you gain 1000 reputation points from suggested edits. Once you hit that privilege your edits no longer go into the review queue so you can't gain any reputation from them. (If you were able to acquire 1000 suggested edits without getting to 2000 overall reputation, I expect your edits would still go for review but you wouldn't get any reputation when they're accepted.)<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *e.g.*, https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
<sup>2</sup> Tag wiki edits will go into the suggested edits review queue until you reach 20,000<sup>3</sup> reputation, so you could conceivably gain reputation for those, but still only up to 1000 total points.
<sup>3</sup> For a "graduated" site. On sites currently in beta, the "trusted user" privilege comes at a much lower reputation level.

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation

And look at the very bottom (last line).

Same with any site in SE network:

```
{site}/reputation
```

> When you reach the maximum, are you notified that you're at your max and don't get anymore rep?

No. Edits will go through the review queue still (unless you reach "Edit questions and answers" privilege and will be able to edit posts instantly), but "edit" events in your reputation tab will have no rep associated with them.

> What happens when you have enough reputation for edits to be applied automatically? Do you still collect reputation for edits after that or do you simply lose the perk at that point?

You don't get any points after you reached the "Edit questions and answers" privilege.